# How to color certain header columns and certain cells of a datagrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I was trying a example to color certain datagrids cell depending on a condition but do not know how to manage color of certain cells with code

> In the following code, the third column will be red if date is even

I am using

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        LoadSummaryMesh();
    }

    private void LoadSummaryMesh()
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("c1");
        dt.Columns.Add("c2");
        dt.Columns.Add("xxx", typeof(DateTime));
        dt.Rows.Add("aa", "" , DateTime.Now.AddDays(0));
        dt.Rows.Add("bb", "" ,DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
        dt.Rows.Add("cc", "" , DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
        this.dataGrid1.DataContext = dt;
    }
}

public class MyBkColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        DataRowView drv = value as DataRowView;
        if (drv != null)
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(drv[2].ToString());
            if (dt.Day % 2 == 0) //If it's a even number day.
                return Brushes.Red;
        }
        return Brushes.White;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    #endregion
}
```

and xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SummaryMesh.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SummaryMesh" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <local:MyBkColorConverter x:Key="bkColorCvrt"/>
        <Style x:Key="LeftAlignmentColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource WrappedColumnHeaderStyle}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="soDataGrid_ColumnHeaderRotateStyle" TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader" >
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding}"
                           FontWeight="Bold" Width="90"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="270" />
                    </TextBlock.LayoutTransform>
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>



        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"  
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  ColumnHeaderStyle ="{StaticResource soDataGrid_ColumnHeaderRotateStyle}"
                  Margin="22,12,18,19" Name="dataGrid1" 
                     xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit">




            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding c1}" Width="80"  Header="c1" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding c2}" Width="80" Header="c2"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding xxx}" Width="80"  Header="xxx">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource bkColorCvrt}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

To get:

[image]

Now the question is how can I color only the second column header blue
and how to color [second column,second row] yellow (using the datatable I am using) ?

something similar to
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 'yellow' cell, you can do as third column.
Add a new converter:

```
    public class MyBkColorConverter2 : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            DataRowView drv = value as DataRowView;
            if (drv != null)
            {
                int rownum = drv.Row.Table.Rows.IndexOf(drv.Row);
                if (rownum == 1)
                {
                    return Brushes.Yellow;
                }
            }
            return Brushes.White;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Add it in xaml:

```
...
<local:MyBkColorConverter2 x:Key="bkColorCvrt2"/>
...

              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding c2}" Width="80" Header="c2">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource soDataGrid_ColumnHeaderRotateStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                    <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <Binding Converter="{StaticResource bkColorCvrt2}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

For column header:

```
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding c2}" Width="80" Header="c2">
                    <DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}" BasedOn="{StaticResource soDataGrid_ColumnHeaderRotateStyle}">
                            <Setter Property="Background">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="Yellow"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
                </DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: when applying the color the header loses the rotation, how to solve it?

Comment: Add BasedOn="{StaticResource soDataGrid_ColumnHeaderRotateStyle}". I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

First about 'yellow' cell you already have an answer, just change `CellStyle` for a second column as you did it for third column.

Second about header: Add style for your `TextBlock` at `DataGridColumnHeader` template, and set required triggers so they will change background, or wrap you `TextBlock` with grid and set it's background based on trigger.